# How i can access / make backup my shopify website before closing store?

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

I have a site on shopify, i want to close my store, how i can make backup of theme files, db, and most important customized options which i have set for future?
Please any body have any idea?

Answer (score 2):

This questions should be forward to the Shopify Support since it's not code related.

That said you need to use an App for export/import. There is no integrated way to export ALL of the content, only specific stuff like customers/products.

You can download the theme manually.

Please note that if you delete your store the image files from the export may disappear depending on the app logic.